# How do I get the parameters from an axios request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

so I've been working on a react App that uses Express as server to communicate with my sql database.
Currently I am trying to retrieve all objects(products) for a user with this call in the frontend:[Frontend axios call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqvxV.png)
Here I'm retrieving a web3 walletaddress which logs correctly, and sending it with the call as a parameter.

Then my server looks like this:
[server side for the call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smxis.png)
It seems like my address variable returns as undefined although I've looked up multiple tutorials and this is the way how they get the parameters from the axios request body.

So like I said, I've tried logging the address variable in the frontend, and it returned the correct value of an address.
I've also tried to not give the parameter as an object, so: just like "[localhost-call], address".

Can anyone help me get the address from the Axios request parameter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with GET.

I mean you can't pass parameters (like `address`) on a `GET` request, if you want to pass a parameter like you want you will need to use another method (such as `POST`, `PUT`, etc...) or you can still use `GET` by using querystring ([Check this link to have another tutorial](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params))
Such as:

```js
// Equivalent to `axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get?address=toto.com')`
const res = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get', { params: { address } });
```

> Note the explicit use of `params` keyword